# MSI LaunchCondition fails for .Net Framework 4.5.1

Tags: installation, .net-framework, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-installer

Currently I have the problem, that running a setup fails at executing / proofing the `LaunchCondition` for `.Net Framework 4.5.1`. But the .net framework is
installed correctly and other applications are running correctly too. The problems
is occuring on a `Windows Server 2012 R2`. I've already tried the .net repair-tool, but nothing seems to help: [.Net Repair tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135)

Also this articles does not help too but contains some important information:

1. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/
2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2006/07/20/repairing-the-windows-installer-service-on-a-64-bit-os/

**EDIT**

The setup uses the following LaunchCondition in the msi file: `MINIMUM_NET_4.5_VERSION_INSTALLED`. This seems to cause the problem.

Has anyone solved this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Rainbow.Core 2.0.0 is not compatible with .Net framework 4.5.1. It needs .Net framework 4.5.2 or higher

Comment: how do you know?